# Server long polls and starts subprocess each call for RFID card number. If this lasts too long, my server will break. How can I do this better?

Tags: python, web, flask, subprocess

I need to get RFID card numbers from an RFID reader.  Client-side initiates this.  Client-side AJAX POSTs to "/user/rfid" route.  This route either returns "error..." or an rfid card number.  Server opens a subprocess that retrieves this number.  If the server sits for a while, and a user tries to log in using RFID the server will break.  I need a better way of accomplishing this, or at least clearing the subprocess perhaps?

Any suggestions?

**Flask Route**

```
@app.route("/user/rfid", methods=["POST"])
def user_rfid():
    rfid = subprocess.Popen(["python", "rfidSimple.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    print("rfid read: %s" % rfid)
    if(rfid == "Exiting...."):
        return json.dumps({"error":"rfid reader failure"})
    else:
        user = db.getUserByRFID(rfid.replace(" ",""))
        if("id" in user.keys()):
            # if credentials match, add user to session
            session["id"]       = user["id"]
            # return redirect url
            return json.dumps({"url":url_for("kiosk")})
        else:
            return json.dumps({"error":"rfid reader failure"})
```

**rfidSimple.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Basic imports
from ctypes import *
import sys
#Phidget specific imports
from Phidgets.PhidgetException import PhidgetErrorCodes, PhidgetException
from Phidgets.Events.Events import AttachEventArgs, DetachEventArgs, ErrorEventArgs, OutputChangeEventArgs, TagEventArgs
from Phidgets.Devices.RFID import RFID, RFIDTagProtocol

# Rudimentary wait system variable
x = True
def rfidTagGained(e):
    global x
    source = e.device
    sys.stdout.write(e.tag)
    x = False

def main():
     #Create an RFID object
    try:
        rfid = RFID()
    except RuntimeError as e:
        sys.stdout.write("Exiting...")
    try:
        rfid.setOnTagHandler(rfidTagGained)
    except PhidgetException as e:
        sys.stdout.write("Exiting...")
    try:
        rfid.openPhidget()
    except PhidgetException as e:
        sys.stdout.write("Exiting...")

    try:
        rfid.waitForAttach(10000)
    except PhidgetException as e:
        # print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
        try:
            rfid.closePhidget()
        except PhidgetException as e:
            sys.stdout.write("Exiting...")
    rfid.setAntennaOn(True)
    while x:
        # wait wait wait!
        pass
    exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't understand... you want a way to timeout the rfidSimple.py if it is taking too long?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a separate thread to read the process stdout. Do a join(timeout) on the thread and if the thread didn't terminate, you know the call has taken too long and you can kill it. Here's an example where its all wrapped into a class. I didn't test it and it may have errors, but you may find the idea useful.

```
import threading
import subprocess
import time

class RfidSimple(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, timeout=10):
        super(theading.Thread, self).__init__()
        self.end = time.time() + timeout
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "rfidSimple.py"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        self._result = self.proc.stdout.read()

    @property
    def result(self):
        timeout = self.end - time.time()
        if timeout > 0:
            self.join(timeout)
            if not self.isAlive():
                self.proc.wait()
                return self._result
        self.proc.terminate()
        self.join(5)
        if not self.isAlive():
            self.proc.wait()
            return "Exiting..."
        raise Exception("could not kill subprocess")

def user_rfid():
    rfid = RfidSimple().result
    print("rfid read: %s" % rfid)
    if(rfid == "Exiting...."):
        return json.dumps({"error":"rfid reader failure"})
    else:
        user = db.getUserByRFID(rfid.replace(" ",""))
        if("id" in user.keys()):
            # if credentials match, add user to session
            session["id"]       = user["id"]
            # return redirect url
            return json.dumps({"url":url_for("kiosk")})
        else:
            return json.dumps({"error":"rfid reader failure"})
```

Comment: I'll try this out and squash errors if they exist.  I won't be able to get back to this project until after work so I'll get to this in the evening.  Here's to hoping this is the better solution!

Comment: Testing now (leaving the AJAX "conversation" on for about 15 minutes).  I have to admit, though.  A possible scenario is if the longpoll recipient does not exist anymore (user logs in using credentials instead of RFID).  There *probably* should only be one thread.

Also, if I log in more than 4 times, my server locks up... Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh